# How does Perplexing Chimera work with Strionic Resonator?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Perplexing Chimera](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Perplexing%20Chimera) and a [Strionic Resonator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Strionic%20Resonator) on the battlefield. My opponent casts Shock. I choose to use my Strionic Resonator's activated ability to copy my Perplexing Chimera's triggered ability. What would happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Perplexing Chimera work with multiple triggers on the stack?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14391/how-does-perplexing-chimera-work-with-multiple-triggers-on-the-stack)

Comment: I think that this is a substantially different case, since having multiple Perplexing Chimera triggers affect the same spell is an unusual case with a different outcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the rulings on the gatherer page you linked for Strionic Resonator,

> The source of the copy is the same as the source of the original ability.

This means that you will have two triggered abilities on the stack, each of which has the effect

> you may exchange control of Perplexing Chimera and that spell. If you do, you may choose new targets for the spell.

This means that, up to twice, you can exchange control of the Shock on the stack and your Perplexing Chimera, and you can choose new targets for the Shock each time. If you do it both times, then you will retain control of your Perplexing Chimera and you will have chosen the target for Shock, though your opponent will still control it.

For reference, the Comprehensive Rules section about [copying objects](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Copying_objects) specifically says in rule 706.10b

> **A copy of an ability has the same source as the original ability.** If the ability refers to its source by name, the copy refers to that same object and not to any other object with the same name. The copy is considered to be the same ability by effects that count how many times that ability has resolved during the turn.

Comment: Does this mean that the Shock is under the opponents control when it resolves? Could this be used as a run-around on hexproof?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. And I guess it could be used to kill something with hexproof.

Comment: So you could use this to change the target of shock to his illusion creature for a split second, causing him to sacrifice it, and then cause it to target his hexproof creature - brilliant!